# Joomla Calendar Field Type

Tags: joomla, module, calendar, fieldtype

I have implemented a module which has a Calendar Type as following:

```
  <field 
                   name="file2calendarEnd" 
                   type="calendar" 
                   default="5-10-2008" 
                   label="End date" 
                   description="Select when the slide will be published" 
                   format="%d %B %Y" />
```

The problem is, when I open the module from the backend, pick a date, for example "23-10-2016" and save it, the next time I open the module , the date will display "22-10-2016". No matter what date I pick, the module will substract a day when I open it.

The date saves correctly on the databse, because if I pick "23-10-2016" on the module, saves it,  and then print it on the frontend, the website will display "23-10-2016" , but if I open the module on the backend, the date will display "22-10-2016".

What can be causing the module to substract a day each time I open the module? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I Test your code on localmachine and it works well.

But got the same issue when i change User Time zone from Default to New York

you can change user timezone in Users > Manage > your user > Basic Settings

You can also check at Global Configuration > Server Settings.

Hope it helps

Comment: You were totally right.. My Joomla was set to New York as time zone.. I changed it to Universal UTC and it worked... thank you!!